# "I forgot" + "to be" in question form. Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I don't know which one of the next sentences are correct. Please, help me to find out. I also will be appreciated if you'll explain which rules we use here. Where I should to put the "is"?

> A) I forgot, how hard **is** it - to be a policeman.
>   B) I forgot, how **is**
>   hard it - to be a policeman.
>   C) I forgot, how hard it - to be a
>   policeman **is**.
>   D) I forgot, how hard it **is** - to be a policeman

I think, A is a correct answer.

Comment: I guess option D) sounds the best (at least to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, since you want to emphasize that you forgot how hard being a policeman is, right answer is D

> I forgot, how hard it is - to be a policeman

Why so? Sentence A sounds like a question. `How hard is it to be a policeman` sounds like a question you would ask someone.

Here you don't want to ask a question. You want to mention a fact and you also want to tell that you forgot that particular fact. Options B and C are structurally wrong and don't lead to anywhere. Only option left now is D!

> **I forgot, how hard it is - to be a policeman**, is the right answer!

Comment: It is an entire sentence. I just wanted to emphasize that to be a policeman is hard.